# My question about installation libgraph on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

I just installed libgraph-1.0.2 on my laptop and I just wrote some code. It compiled successfully but for execution time the Terminal shows me :

```
user@user-Vostro-2520:~$ gcc demo.c -o demo -lgraph
user@user-Vostro-2520:~$ ./demo
./demo: error while loading shared libraries: libgraph.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
user@user-Vostro-2520:~$
```

Why this happened?

Comment: Please describe what you have: which version of Ubuntu. And what the demo program is doing. - Try to get help also at one of the Ubuntu Forums for programming, https://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=310

Comment: `sudo cp /usr/local/lib/libgraph.* /usr/lib`  should fix it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to summarize *how* you installed libgraph-1.0.2. @Rinzwind are we sure the lib is in /usr/local/lib? wouldn't running `ldconfig` be preferable in that case anyhow?